# Webhook no devuelve los mensajes api whatsapp

Tags: nodejs, api, whatsapp, webhook

Hola compañeros espero se encuentren muy bien el día de hoy, estoy creando un webhook para recibir y enviar mensajes usando la API cloud de whatsapp pero al momento de obtener el numero telefónico me agrega un 1 después del codigo del país cuando hago un `myConsole.log(value);`

```
{
 from: '**521**999368XXXX',
 id: '',
 timestamp: '1670184900',
 text: { body: 'RESPONDEEEE' },
 type: 'text'
}
```

¿Cómo puedo quitar ese numero 1 ? estoy usando nodejs con express casi no eh avanzado mucho en mi código estoy atorado en esa parte, saludos.

```
const ReceivedMessage = (req, res) => {
  try {
    var entry = (req.body["entry"])[0];
    var changes = (entry["changes"])[0];
    var value = changes["value"];

    var messageObject = value["messages"];
    if (typeof messageObject != "undefined") {
      var messages = messageObject[0];

      var number = messages["from"];
      var text = GetTextuser(messages);
      myConsole.log(messageObject[0]);
      whatsappservice.SendMessagesWhatsapp("el usuario dijo "+text,number)
    }
    res.send("EVENT_RECEIVED");
  } catch (error) {
    myConsole.log(error);
    res.send("EVENT_RECEIVED");
  }
}
```

Comment: México? puede ser un remanente del cambio de formato ver https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Mexico#Dialing_prefixes_prior_to_2019 y https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmeros_de_tel%C3%A9fono_en_M%C3%A9xico#Prefijos_Anteriores "Para la marcación a números fijos desde el extranjero no hubo cambios ya que los nuevos números se componen del NIR que se usaba hasta agosto de 2019 y el número telefónico, para la marcación a números celulares se eliminó el 1 que seguía al código de país, pasando de +52 1 a +52."

Comment: 2/ en la versión inglés no se ve código de area empezando con 1 así que podrías asumir que `+52 1` es equivalente  a `+52`